# Auto submitting form on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a form on page load.

```
<?php if($abc == $xyz){ ?>
<form action="register.php" id="testform">
...form content...
</form>
<?php }  else{ ?>
Error
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('testform').submit();
};
</script>
```

Auto submitting the form works fine, but it is rechecking the condition `<?php if($abc = $xyz){ ?>` while submitting. How to stop it from performing the same action again?

Comment: That's not a valid comparison using only `=`. Why do you need a form to auto submit on page load in the first place?

Comment: I am integrating a payment gateway. I am getting data on this page by submitting the form on previous page. So i need it to save in db first then redirect to payment gateway. Above code is just for the understanding.

Comment: Well if you submit back to this same page you execute all the same code again so question really isn't clear

Comment: hope your page getting refresh so that again it rechecking condition. can you use jquery submit and also use event.preventDefault function to avoid refresh

Comment: I dont want to execute all the code again. I just want to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Jquery, here is an answer with `jquery`.

**The this one is using the jquery post request, but ignoring the response.**

```
window.onload = function(){
    $.post('server.php', $('#testform').serialize())
};
```

**This one is using the jquery post request, but working with response.**

```
window.onload = function(){

    var url = "register.php"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#testform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data);
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

[Complete reference of jquery form submit](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: what to do if i want to redirect to register.php page? I dont need result on the same page.

Comment: in the sucess call back, instead of alert, just change the location to `register.php`

Answer (score 1):

When you use document.getElementById('testform').submit();
The page will be reload again that why it rechecking condition 

To avoid page reload you can use ajax submit data to register.php action.
Example Ajax with Jquery

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "register.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Hope it help!